# Gtk.ListStore Value Error

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I am trying to build a combobox that is dynamic. So when a specific text file is updated, then the combobox will follow suit. However, I am having issues with building my list view. I am getting the following Error. ValueError: row sequence has wrong length. Below is the code I am using. There is only one column for my list. My list is ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', '...etc']. Could someone please help me out with understanding what I am missing. Thank you!

```
def newlist(self, widget): 
    LRU_list = gtk.ListStore(str)
    for i in range(len(LRU)):
        LRU_list.append(LRU[i])<---- Value Error


    for row in LRU_list:
        print(row[:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a list:

```
def newlist(self, widget): 
    LRU_list = gtk.ListStore(str)
    for i in range(len(LRU)):
        LRU_list.append([LRU[i]])<---- Value Error


    for row in LRU_list:
        print(row[:])
```